# Attach a input element with a Form using jQuery

Tags: html, jquery

How to attach a input element with a Form using jQuery ?

I have a `Form` like below.

```
<form action="{{ route('update_profile') }}" method="POST" id="buildyourform"
                                            enctype="multipart/form-data">
<div class="form-group">
   <label for="exampleFormControlFile1">Company Logo</label>
   <div id="company_logo">
       <i class="ri-close-line" title="Click to Update Image"></i> 
   </div>
</div>
<div class="flex-row">
  <div class=" d-flex justify-content-end ">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mb-5 mt-3">Update</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

I am trying to place `<input type="file" class="form-control-file" name="company_logo" />` inside `<div id="company_logo"></div>` using jQuery.

I am using below jQuery code.

```
var fName = $("<input type=\"file\" class=\"form-control-file\" name=\"company_logo\" />");

$("#company_logo .ri-close-line").click(function() {    
  $("#company_logo").html(fName);
});
```

But this code is not working when I submit the `Form`.

Below code is working.

```
var fName = $("<input type=\"file\" class=\"form-control-file\" name=\"company_logo\" />");

$("#company_logo .ri-close-line").click(function() {    
  $("#buildyourform").append(fName);
});
```

How to attach a input element with a Form using jQuery ?

Comment: I don't see any reason why it wouldn't work. After you attach the input, do you select a file with it?

Comment: Your HTML looks malformed. `</form>` should be after the last `</div>`

Comment: Thanks @Barmar. Yes, I selected file with it.